# How to export a data base from DataGrip at one SQL file?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

How I can export a data base from DataGrip at one SQL file as   phpmyadmin export?

If I use Dump Data To Files, DataGrip save one table at one file.

And how I can create backup of all MySQL databases, which open in DataGrip?

Comment: The team of DataGrip expects to have the tool integrated with mysqldump in 2016.3 version

Answer (score 35):

Old thread here, but for those who may stumble upon it, the newer versions of DataGrip have a new option, "dump with mysqldump", that will let you generate a dump contained in a single .sql output file.

[image]

Comment: If you can elaborate on that maybe I can help.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that the tables that are outputted are inaccurate?

Comment: I haven't - have you?

Comment: Hm, I think this functionality works fine for me now, 3 months ago I was new to DataGrip but now I have no problems with it. Thanks for following up!

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but has anybody found a way to use the Dump with 'mysqldump' option via an SSH tunnel (where the local machine doesn't have mysql nor mysqldump installed)?

Answer (score 13):

Running DataGrip 2016.2.5 you can select sever tables and right click->Copy DDL.  That puts a drop/create script on the clipboard, which you can then paste into a text file.

Comment: I couldn't find `Copy DDL` in *table context menu* in **DataGrip v2018.2**. But there is a choice that seems to be the same: `R-Click on a table -> SQL Scripts -> Source Editor` **`(Ctrl+B)`**

Answer (score 5):

I just got the DataGrip 2016.2.1 update this morning. It looks like the feature has been added (at least for SQL SERVER, the only one I tested). It wasn't available in the previous version - I tried.

Select a range of tables and right-click on them, or right-click on the database name. The `Dump Data to Files` option is now there.

Unfortunately, it still dumps to multiple files. But it beats the heck out of right-clicking on each table in turn.

Comment: is there a way to dump the data with just specific columns, for example, I don't want it to export the `id` column

Answer (score 3):

You can now tick "Single File" while choosing "Dump Data to File(s)" in DataGrip 2018.3.1[image]

Comment: It looks like this option was removed again